# SubSurface-Mirror Problem

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror, subdivision-surface

I am beginner, I am trying to made a car bumper and problem appears when I want to mirror my model (I modeled a right side half of bumper because is symmetric).

When I use only mirror modifier all is fine but when I want add subsurface modifier, my model has some bugs and mistakes.

[image: With mirror and subsurface modifier]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Marko, just curious simply ... Toyota MR2 or Lotus Esprit bumper or some completely different? ;)

Comment: Hi Jan, this is BMW e30 M3 bumper , but looks similar like a Lotus Esprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing could be that the middle of your bumper model, where the mirroring starts, isn't completely flat along the x-axis. You can fix this by selecting the vertices, scaling and then pressing <kbd>X</kbd> and <kbd>0</kbd>.

After flattening the vertices, go to the properties panel by hitting <kbd>N</kbd> and put the vertice group to 0 on the x-axis.

Here are some pictures:

[image]
The situation

[image]
Select these vertices

[image]
Scale to 0 on the x axis

[image]
X co-ordinate to 0